# respond_with nested models renders wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For resources that are nested so each `Driver` has_many `Bookings`:

```
resources :drivers do 
    resources :bookings
end
```

In the `bookings` controller 'create' action, I have:

```
respond_with(@booking.driver, @booking)
```

When I call the create action, after correctly creating a booking, it should render the `show` page. It renders the right page, but the address is that of the `index`:

```
https://localhost:3000/drivers/30/bookings
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:3000/drivers/30/bookings/47
```

which means that if you refresh the `show` page, it tries to take you to the "index" page, rather than the "show"

Comment: I think the quick fix would be to pass a location option. Something like: `respond_with(@booking.driver, @booking, location: drivers_booking_url(@booking))`

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried it with the exact same issue. `respond_with(@booking.driver, @booking, location: driver_booking_path(@booking.driver, @booking))`. It seems like it's flashing up with the correct url, then changing it. I'm using jquery mobile, could that be doing it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the Jquery mobile I'm using. I've tried using data: { ajax: 'false' } on the form, and disabling ajax across the site, but to no effect.

Comment: Sounds like that could be the culprit. I just spun up a new Rails 4 app (using the Responders gem) and this scenario works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for having a look :). That's really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jquery Mobile, which was changing the url.

The solution was to add  data-url="<%= request.path %>" to the  div of the page to be reached.